How to use ParallelTable in NDSolve?
I can't find NDSolveValue in S[1]、S[2] if I use ParallelTable
However, If I keep all same as ParallelTable except repace ParallelTable with Table, I do get
NDSolveValue in S[1]、S[2].

I want to know how to find NDSolveValue and use them in ParallelTable case.
ParallelTable[S[j] = NDSolve[{{A''[x] + A[x] == 0}, 
                              {A[1000] == E^(I*1000), A'[1000] == I*E^(I*1000)}}, 
                             {A[x], A'[x]}, {x, 1000, 10^-15}], {j, 1, 2, 1}]
(* You can't find NDSolvevalue by rule, don't believe? try below *)
(A'[x] /. S[2]) /. x -> 10^0
(* ha, receive a warning? just replace ParallelTable with Table, try below *)
Table[S[j] = NDSolve[{{A''[x] + A[x] == 0}, 
                      {A[1000] == E^(I*1000),  A'[1000] == I*E^(I*1000)}}, 
                     {A[x], A'[x]}, {x, 1000,  10^-15}], {j, 1, 2, 1}]
(A'[x] /. S[2]) /. x -> 10^0

Thank you for your attention! Your suggestions are so helpful for me!

S = ParallelTable[NDSolve[{{A''[x] + A[x] == 0}, {A[1000] == E^(I*1000), A'[1000] == I*E^(I*1000)}}, {A[x], A'[x]}, {x, 1000, 10^-15}], {j, 1, 3, 1}]``(A'[x] /. S[[1]]) /. x -> 10^0This method can find NDSolveValue in S ,but I still don't know how to find NDSolveValue if someone have defined S[j] just like I do in my question

To be more specific, you need SetSharedFunction.

Put S out of ParallelTable
S = ParallelTable[
  NDSolve[{{A''[x] + A[x] == 0}, {A[1000] == E^(I*1000), 
     A'[1000] == I*E^(I*1000)}}, {A[x], A'[x]}, {x, 1000, 
    10^-15}], {j, 1, 2, 1}]

(A'[x] /. S[[2]]) /. x -> 10^0

As for your comment, this helps:
Clear[S, S1];
S1 = ParallelTable[
  NDSolve[{{A''[x] + A[x] == 0}, {A[1000] == E^(I*1000), 
     A'[1000] == I*E^(I*1000)}}, {A[x], A'[x]}, {x, 1000, 
    10^-15}], {j, 1, 2, 1}]
S[i_] := S1[[i]]
(A'[x] /. S[2]) /. x -> 10^0


Thank you! yes,you are right! but if I have defined S just like my question,what could I do? I run a total day for hundreds differential questions. My god! Need I run them again?

@ScrippsMoore Yes, there exists no way to save your work AFAIK. It's better to learn a bit about parallelization before using it, it's not as sweet as it looks like. You may want to read e.g. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/182034/1871 and https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48295/1871 . BTW, the next pitfall waiting for you is probably DistributedContexts.

@ScrippsMoore See my update.

@xzczd Thank you very much！Very helpful materials. I would remember add SetSharedFunction[S] before ParallelTable[S[j] = NDSolve[], {j, 1, 2, 1}] I have given up struggling, gone to sleep,

@ScrippsMoore I retract my words "there exists no way to save your work" 囧. Just found your work can be saved with ParallelEvaluate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104009/1871
